# Indent paragraph after definition

Tags: indentation

I'm looking to accomplish something like this (example done in Word):

[image]
Basically, after a heading, every line should be spaced a varied amount. Please let me know if there is a package which supports this. Thank you.

Comment: Will all your definitions have to be automatically numbered, i.e. is it a theorem-like structure?

Comment: @Bernard That would work as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hanging`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hanging?lang=en) package provides support for hanging indents.

> The hang­ing pack­age fa­cil­i­tates the type­set­ting of hang­ing para­graphs.
>
> The pack­age also en­ables type­set­ting with hang­ing punc­tu­a­tion, by mak­ing punc­tu­a­tion char­ac­ters ac­tive. This fa­cil­ity is best sup­pressed (it can in­ter­fere with other pack­ages) — there are pack­age op­tions for sup­press­ing each in­di­vid­ual punc­tu­a­tion char­ac­ter. ‘Real’ at­tempts at hang­ing punc­tion should nowa­days use the mi­crotype pack­age, which takes ad­van­tage of the sup­port of­fered in re­cent ver­sions of pdfTeX.

Use the command `\hangpara{<indent>}{<afternum>}` at the start of the paragraph, where `<indent>` is the length to indent the paragraph by, and `<afternum>` is the number of lines to not be indented at the start of the paragraph (in your case, 1).

However, you mention hanging indents after headings, in which case the `description` environment, which is a part of base LaTeX, might be more appropriate.

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Definition 1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
\end{description}
```